# How do I transfer a Python virtual environment to another user?

Tags: python, linux, unix

Currently, I created a virutal environment in my

- /home/myuser/my_virtual_env/

How do I copy this entire thing to another user? (and perhaps rename it to thatuser_virtual_env)
? I have to copy all the python packages, and eveyrthing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'official' method is to create virtualenv this way: `virtualenv --relocatable ENV`.
Check the 'Making Environments Relocatable' section here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

But I think the way to go is not to copy the environment (that's quite error prone) but to script the environment creation.
You can auto-generate a pip requirements file using `pip freeze` command and then tweak it manually.